# Is there a TFS policy to allow only merges and not edits?

Tags: tfs, merge, policy

We have a baseline folder and development branches in TFS. We'd like to add a policy where changes can only be *merged* into the baseline from a development branch and not edited directly unless you override the policy. How can we do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to enforce this restriction 100%.  Options:

- write a checkin policy [but they can be overridden]
- write an event hook that notifies you [or takes some other action] when someone commits something that wasn't a merge
- restrict checkin permissions on the branch to trusted developers / integration managers [but they themselves would have full rights]

There's an example of a "merge only" checkin policy here: http://leon.mvps.org/TFS/MergeOnlyPolicy.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You might consider limiting the security on those branches to the person(s) who would be responsible enough to do it right.

Comment: I noticed the "Change" column in the Check In window has the word "merge", not "edit" when I merge back to the baseline. Are you saying a policy can't check this value?

Comment: A merge is sometimes an edit, but not always.  An edit is sometimes a merge, but not always.  One does not imply the other.